# SharePoint Behaved Types - Run Pex Explorations error (System.Moles 4.0.0.0)

Tags: unit-testing

was following a tutorial on pex and moles (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pexsharepoint.pdf). Its a year old, but everything worked fine until I changed Mole types to Behaved types. Once I did that, 'Run Pex Explorations' command started throwing this exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Moles, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ae41878053f6703' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried multiple solution (including [Moles and SharePoint Behaviour types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975474/moles-and-sharepoint-behaviour-types)). I also tried to generate Moles for System 4.0.0.0 assembly, but that fails with multiple 'cannot find suitable method to override' errors.

I'm using the latest version on pex (0.94) and moles (1.0.0.0). Is there any solution for this?

Comment: i got it working by copying all behaved types into my test project and referencing Microsoft.ExtendedReflection, System.Moles 2.0, and System.Web 2.0. Is there a better way to get this to work?